# How to generate codes for the users to register in the application

Tags: flutter, dart, mobile

I'm working on a flutter application and I want to make the registration form for the people who get the code!

There's a text field on the register form, the user should take the code, write it there and if it's correct => done, not correct => There's an error!

How can I make that?

Answer (score 2):

You'll need some form of validation. One way this could be achieved is to have a separate system generate the random codes, and store them. Any time you receive a code during registration, you query that other system and check to see if has generated that code.

So basically these are the functionalities of the systems:

## System 1

1. Generate code - store, and return the generated code to the caller. Internal use only.

---

2. Validate a code - return true if valid, else false

---

3. Remove a code - returns true if a code is successfully removed, false if no code removed (ex: invalid code, database error, etc)

---

## System 2

1. Request code. The user enters their information and will eventually receive a code

---

2. Already have a code. The User registers using their code and it's validated by System 1

Separating the code generation and validation away from your app is a good security measure, but if this is just a toy app for practice, you could also include it within your application.

---

Another option would be to have an acceptable *format* for the codes. That way anything that matches the format is considered a valid code. This is insecure because if someone finds out the format, they can distribute unlimited (or as many as the format allows) codes. You would also have to store the used codes or let codes be reused. If you're going to store the used codes, you might as well take the other route and store only the available to be used codes (less storage used). If you decide to take the format route, you'll need to make sure that the format is sufficiently difficult to guess randomly so people can't guess random codes over and over and get one easily.

Overall, it really depends on the needs of your application. If you need something secure, I would look to see if there's an already vetted solution out there. If it needs mild security, you can implement it yourself using firebase/cloud functions. If security isn't an issue, you can decide on a format that is considered *valid*, and as long as the code entered matches that format it allows registration.